# how to capture data of a scale(mettler - toledo 8530) on vb.net usb?

Tags: vb.net

ok the scale is a truck scale connected to a terminal (cougar 8530) that was connected before via Rs232 now the pcs doesnt have a serial port so someoney attach a usb adapter to it the thing is i cant capture any data from it. im an developing a small program that can capture the weight of the truck (trucks are weight with the product and then re-weight with out it so they can find how much the product or products weight) so any ideas? suggestions? 
thanks on advance for any input

maxxxx

Answer (score 0):

Is the USB adapter just a COM port? If it is it should show up as a new COM port, probably not COM1 or COM2, maybe COM3 or COM4, depends on the computer.

Try the `System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.GetPortNames()` function to get a string array of valid port names, and try each one to see which port the scale is connected to.